# boost::future .then() continuations returning boost::future

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, boost, future

I was reading the new C++ proposal regarding improvements to `std::future` and `std::promise` here http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3857.pdf and it says

> It is a common situation that the body of a then function object will
>   itself be a future-based operation, which leads to the then()
>   returning a future>. In this case, it is almost always the
>   case that what you really care about is the inner future, so then()
>   performs an implicit unwrap() (see below) before returning.

Therefore in the following code

```
auto promise = std::promise<int>{};
auto another_future = promise.get_future().then([](auto future) {
    return std::async([]() { return 1; });
});
```

the type of `another_future` is `std::future<int>` and not `std::future<std::future<int>>`

I was trying to use `boost::future` to achieve the same thing but it seems like boost continuations do not implicitly unwrap the future.  Is there something I can do to enable the same behavior from boost futures?  It seems like there is no `unwrap()` function available to use on the resulting feature either.

Am I stuck with having to unwrap the future via a constructor manually?  Also on trying that I get the following error, what should I do?

```
inline explicit BOOST_THREAD_FUTURE(
    BOOST_THREAD_RV_REF(
        BOOST_THREAD_FUTURE<BOOST_THREAD_FUTURE<R> >) other); // EXTENSION
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unwrapping is a conditional extension for Boost Thread:

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE_UNWRAP
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE_CONTINUATION
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

int main() {
    auto promise = boost::promise<int>{};
    boost::future<int> another_future = 
        promise.get_future().then([](auto) {
            return boost::async([]() { return 1; });
        }).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Those three constants are automatically set when you `#define BOOST_THREAD_VERSION 4`